# How to reopen stdout?

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to mix wide and ansi versions of console output in my program (printf() and wprintf() or cout and wcout ). The documentation to fwide() function says, that

> "By calling this function, the orientation can be explicitly
>   established before any i/o operation. Calling this function on a
>   stream that already has an orientation cannot change it (only after a
>   call to freopen can a stream with an established orientation change
>   it)."

As I understand this, after reopening stdout one can call wprintf() even after printf() has already been called.

Could someone advise how to call reopen() function for stdout?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use `wprintf` and avoid `printf`?

Comment: Different parts of source code written in different time use different functions for output.